# parsing of TCP DNS Request using Scapy

Tags: sockets, scapy

In need of tutleage with parsing of TCP DNS Request using Scapy.

This is how I  dissect an incoming UDP DNS request:

```
In [1]: from scapy.all import *
In [10]: udp_request=b' \xaa\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03cnn\x03com\x00\x00\x10\x00\x01'
In [11]: DNS(udp_request).qd
Out[11]: <DNSQR  qname='cnn.com.' qtype=TXT qclass=IN |>
```

That's just peachy! However, I am struggling with looking into an incoming DNS request which uses TCP.

```
In [12]: tcp_request = b'\x00\x19\x83\xec\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03cnn\x03com\x00\x00\x10\x00\x01'
In [13]: DNS(tcp_request)
Out[13]: <DNS  id=25 qr=1 opcode=QUERY aa=0 tc=1 rd=1 ra=1 z=1 ad=1 cd=0 rcode=12 qdcount=256 ancount=1 nscount=0 arcount=0 qd='' an=<DNSRR  rrname='.' type=MD rclass=25454 ttl=1845715823 rdata='' |> ns=None ar=None |>
In [14]: DNS(tcp_request).qd
Out[14]: b''
```

Notice, it is showing a blank output. I've been searching, and apparantly this is possible (ref: https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/819 et al). How can I make it work?

Comment: How do you get this string ? Are you sure it is a DNS layer and not a TCP one with a DNS payload ?

Comment: I've a python script that listens on port 53, udp and tcp. From another host, I'd send a (UDP) DNS request, to which we'd respond with TrunCation set. The client would then retry in TCP. udp_request,  tcp_request are thus harvested respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Per [rfc1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-4.2.2), the first two byte fields of a TCP message contains the length of the rest of the message. This checksout:

```
In [18]: tcp_request
Out[18]: b'\x00\x19\x83\xec\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03cnn\x03com\x00\x00\x10\x00\x01'

In [19]: len(_)
Out[19]: 27

In [20]: tcp_request[0] << 8 | tcp_request[1]
Out[20]: 25
```

So really all I needed to do was the give to scapy the rest of payload, which is the actual DNS message:

```
In [21]: DNS(tcp_request[2:])
Out[21]: <DNS  id=33772 qr=0 opcode=QUERY aa=0 tc=0 rd=1 ra=0 z=0 ad=0 cd=0 rcode=ok qdcount=1 ancount=0 nscount=0 arcount=0 qd=<DNSQR  qname='cnn.com.' qtype=TXT qclass=IN |> an=None ns=None ar=None |>
```